# writing csv with special characters to a database table

Tags: python

I have a csv file that has special characters, something like below -

```
location_id          location_name
7099395                SUPER CAFÃ‰
```

I first read the file into a `dataframe` and then wrote the `dataframe` into a database table using `sqlalchemy`.

Because of special characters I am getting the following error:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 33-39: ordinal not in range(128)
```

To work around this, I used `unidecode` module in a function but that converted the `df` into a `string`. On subsequently converting the `string` back to a `df` using `StringIO` module, it distorted the tabular form. If needed, I will be happy to paste my code here for reference.

EDIT: Following is my code -

```
from unidecode import unidecode
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

def unicodize(item):
    def _get_int_if_int(x):
        try:
            if not abs(int(x) - float(x)) > 0:
                return int(x)
            else:
                return x
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            return x

    try:
        if item.__contains__("_"):
            _item = item
        elif item.startswith("0") and len(item) > 1:
            _item = item
        else:
            _item = _get_int_if_int(item)
    except AttributeError:
        _item = _get_int_if_int(item)

    try:
        try:
            return unidecode(unicode(_item))
        except NameError:
            return unidecode(str(_item))
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            try:
                return unidecode(_item.decode('utf-8'))
            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                return unidecode(_item.decode('latin-1'))
    except AttributeError:
        return _item

input = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv')
output = (unicodize(input))

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(output), sep='\t')

output_df_dict = {}
output_df_dict['my_file'] = df
engine = create_engine('postgres://XX:YY@ZZ:5432/AA')
schema = "scenario_3"
for table_name, df in output_df_dict.items():
     df['jqgrid_id'] = df.index
     df.to_sql(table_name, con=engine, schema=schema, index=False, if_exists='replace')
     print("Data Transfer done!")
```

I do get the output written in the database table however its form is totally distorted and the table shows counts too. (snapshot attached)[image]

Comment: It seems likely that the root cause is that, somewhere or other, you're calling `decode` on something that's already a `unicode` object, which Python 2 allows, but handles by first doing `s.encode(sys.getdefaultencoding())` so it has something it can decode. And, since `sys.getdefaultencoding()` is usually `'ascii'`, that usually fails. But it's hard to guess _where_ you're doing that (possibly even doing it indirectly), so unless that's enough for you to figure it out yourself, you need to show us the relevant code, not just describe it.

Comment: Just added my code to the question!

Comment: Which line are you getting the exception on? Is it that `return unidecode(_item.decode('latin-1'))`? Also, can you show us the raw bytes of that row? Is it `'SUPER CAF\xc3\x83\xe2\x80\xb0'` (meaning you've already mojikbake'd something into UTF-8 and need to repair it), or something different? And finally, if you `print type(_item), repr(_item)` right before all that `unidecode` code, what does it say?

Comment: I do get the output written in the database table however its form is totally distorted and the table shows counts too.  I will have answers to your questions in few minutes.

Comment: When you say you "have a csv file", you don't really have it unless you have all the metadata required for basic interpretation, the most basic of which is (like for any text file) the character encoding it was written with. Until you have that, all you have is a file of bytes.